# ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1122)

Tags: python

I have used the API of BaiduMap, and the port of API's configuration is * to keep my connection with the API, but the terminal still told me the protocol error. It's my first time using requests package. I've install certifi, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com). You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Requests library needs to verify SSL configuration.

You need to add verify option like that

```
requests.get('https://www.example.com', verify=False)
```

Comment: thanks 4 your help.Its my computer's question for I enabled network manual proxy. when I turned off my proxy, SSL configuration was verified.

Answer (score 0):

try to add a environment variables

```
name:HTTPS_PORXY
value:http://proxy_ip:proxy_port
```

search in windows10 setting for proxy ,and you can see the ip and port

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue recently. Even though I specified `verify=False` I was getting SSLError.

I downgraded python version from 3.11.3 to 3.9.12, and it started working. Tried with 3.11.0 too and it works.

I guess there is some issue with 3.11.3 python version.